# Wifi is interfering with Bluetooth headset

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth

Wifi is interfering with Bluetooth headset in my Ubuntu system. When i disconnect wifi then it works fine but when i connect it back again same problem.

While googling it I found some coexistence term that i tried but still same problem.

Please help.

Comment: wifi and bluetooth use the same device. you may not be able to solve this issue.

Comment: You want to say this problem can't be solved? But it is working fine in Windows.

Comment: It may also be a driver issue. Try with booting a recent Ubuntu version (16.04.2 or 17.04) to see whether then you then can have WiFi and Bluetooth simultaneously.

Comment: well not unsolvable, but may require linux drivers from the card manufacturer (often unavailable). which card do you have?

Comment: @ravery you mean to say wifi card?

Comment: yes, who makes the wifi card

Comment: @ravery Realtek Rtl8723be

Comment: I had issues with my realtech wifi card, let me see if I can find the link for the new drivers again.

Answer (score 1):

realtech has had issues with repo drivers:
try these drivers : https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

download all the files:

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

enter the directory where you downloaded the files and open a terminal there (right click-->action-->open term)

type make

then sudo make install

Comment: I guess you took it wrong, I have no issues with wifi connectivity. When i connect my ubuntu pc to wifi then bluetooth headset already connected starts giving distorted noise. Means headset voice starts to disrupt.

Comment: bluetooth uses the wifi card, it is a signal filter on the radio card

Comment: can you tell me commands that i need to run to update that driver?

Comment: I added directions to my answer